# CommandBar color in UWP

Tags: xamarin, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml, xamarin.windows

I have a Xamarin project with UWP and need to set background color of Top Command Bar in UWP.
I tried adding following in App.xaml in Shared Project (this gives error):

```
<Style TargetType="CommandBar">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="#F44336" />                 
</Style>
```

I also tried adding following in App.xaml in UWP project:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style TargetType="AppBar">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#F44336"/>               
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>        
</Application.Resources>
```

Nothing notable change happened. Can anyone please help?

Comment: You can set **Background** property of **CommandBar** with the color of your choice.

Comment: @HobbyDev isn't that what the OP already tries to do?